# Show that there is a neighborhood around $0$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

The full question is : $f(z)$ is analytic at $z= 0$ and we know that $f(0) \neq 0$. Show that there is a neighborhood around $0$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$.

I have solved this problem before, but when i looked back i do not understand again.

> What i do understand is the most intuitive way, since $f(z)$ is
>   analytic at $0$, it is by definition analytic around a small
>   neighborhood of $0$. In details, take a open ball around $0$, call it
>   $B(0,R)$, then $f(z)$ is analytic throughout this open ball. Then,
>   since we know that in a analytic domain there can not be infinitely
>   many zeroes. Hence there are finite number of zeroes in this region.
>   So take the zero with the  minimum distance from the origin, call it
>   $r$, form a ball $B(0,r)$, or you can form a ball $B(0,\dfrac{r}{2})$
>   then we guarantee there is no zeroes inside.

However, some of my mentors have another more rigorous approach involving the identity theorem, however, they did not elaborate and hence i cannot figure how does identity theorem play a part here. In fact, one of the person on this forum answered me before, but i still cannot figure out: here is his answer

we can ensure that $g(z)$ does not have a zero in the neighbourhood of $0$ that we choose by choosing a small enough neighbourhood.If $g$ had zeros in **every neighbourhood** (Why is he mentioning every neighborhood?) of $0$, then $0$ would be a limit point of zeros of $g$, and hence we would have that $g(0)=0$ by continuity. (In fact we would have that $g$ is identically $0$, since non-constant analytic functions have isolated zeros.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the fact that $f$ is continuous at $z=0$, which is a way weaker assumption than the analycity. Write the epsilon-delta definition of continuity at $0$ with $\epsilon = \lvert f(0) \rvert /2$.

In your post, you give two proofs that are moslty equivalent and use the [principle of permanence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_permanence). Both are correct but it is way too complicated to show such a simple fact.

Let me rewrite the second proof :

> By contradiction, assume that every neighbourhood of $0$ contains a zero of $f$. Then there is a sequence $(z_n)$ of zeros of $f$ that converges to $0$. Indeed, consider the open ball centered at $0$ with radius $1/n$. It is a neighbourhood of $0$, hence it contains a zero $z_n$. By the principle of permanence, the set of zeros of $f$ has a limit point, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes i know that theorem as well now you mentioned it, however, i still do not understand the identity theorem approach, in which im keen to know.

Comment: @ilovewt : i have rewrote the original proof in my answer.

Comment: @yanko : continuity at $0$ is sufficient.

Comment: Hi, yes i understand this theorem now, but i do not understand why the contradiction has to be Every neighborhood of $0$. Why cant my contradiction be suppose there is a zero (Just one zero) in the said neighborhood...etc

Comment: @ilovewt : the negation of "there is a neighbourhood that doesn't contain any zero" is "every neighbourhood contains at least one zero".

Comment: Ah thanks, I think that why I was stuck. I didn't know the contradiction was every neighbor hood

Comment: @tristan can we make lower bound (rather than 0) of $|f|$ in some nbhd?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z_n)=0$ and $|z_n| \leq 1/n$. Then $0$ would be a limit point for the set of zeroes of $f$, and this would imply that $f$ is identically zero because non-zero analytic functions have isolated zeros.

So if $f$ is not the zero function there exists $n$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $|z| < 1/n$, that is what you want.

Comment: Would you care to explain why having isolated zeros will imply identically zero.

Comment: If $f$ is a non-zero analytic function, its set of zeroes is without limit points (i.e, the zeroes are isolated). This is equivalent to say that if the zero set of $f$ has a limit point then $f$ is identically zero.